# Jquery .submit() doesnt fire / do anything

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jquery to validate the form before the actual submit. the validation works fine, but when I use `.submit()` to submit the form, it doesn't do anything. I have seen answers from other forum but none of it works.

I've renamed the name of the elements `("submit")` so it won't cause conflict, I have tried to do the validation inside the `.submit()` function, but it still doesn't work

here is my form

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="info_employee">
    <table>
        <colgroup>
            <col width="200px">
            <col width="10px">
            <col>
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Division</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><select name="division" id="division">
                '.$opsi_division.'
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Posisi</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="position"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><select name="status" id="status">
                '.$opsi_status.'
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="date_status" id="date_status" readonly="readonly"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="'.($edit == true ? 'save_edit' : 'save_new').'">
        <button type="submit" id="save" value="Save">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and here is my jQuery, which is inside $(document).ready(function(){

```
var conf, conf_t;
$('body').on('click', '#save', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    conf = 0;
    conf_t = 0;

    conf_t++;
    if($('input[name="name"]').val() == ''){
        empty_blink($('input[name="name"]'));
    }else{
        conf++;
    };

    conf_t++;
    if($('#division').val() == '' || $('#division').val() == null){
        empty_blink($('#division'));
    }else{
        conf++;
    };

    conf_t++;
    if($('input[name="position"]').val() == ''){
        empty_blink($('input[name="position"]'));
    }else{
        conf++;
    };

    conf_t++;
    if($('#status').val() == '' || $('#status').val() == null){
        empty_blink($('#status'));
    }else{
        conf++;
    };

    conf_t++;
    if($('input[name="date_status"]').val() == ''){
        empty_blink($('input[name="date_status"]'));
    }else{
        conf++;
    };

    if(conf == conf_t){
        console.log(conf, conf_t);
        $('#info_employee').submit();
    }else{
        console.log(conf, conf_t);
        notif('You must fill all field', 0);
    }
});
```

I have other form which is almost exact copy of these code and it works for the other form, but not this one

please help

**EDIT**
here are code for notif() and empty_blink()

```
function notif(message, status){
   if(status == 1){ //success
      $('#notification').css('background-color','#2D53A0').css('border','3px solid white').text(message).fadeIn(500).delay(500).fadeOut(500);
   }else if(status == 0){ //failed
      $('#notification').css('background-color','#F52F2F').text(message).fadeIn(500).delay(500).fadeOut(500);
   }
}

function empty_blink(el){
   el.css('background-color','#FFCCCC', '!important');
}
```

Comment: try with native form submit event as : `$('#info_employee')[0].submit();`

Comment: I tried to run your code in jsfiddle and empty_blink is not defined, can you please add that code as well.

Comment: Also just FYI, avoid using "==" instead of that use "===". Since it checks for the datatype as well with the value.

Comment: If you comment out the functions empty_blink() and notif() the code you supplied works well in jsfiddle

Comment: You are not using the standard way of HTML Form element. Plus I found  some Junk code in HTML tag <select> e.g. '.$opsi_division.'

Comment: any console error ? Could u pls provide form action value and try again ?

Comment: Using Bootstrap from validation will minimize your efforts. https://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/

Comment: I have made some changes in your code and found that the code is working fine, the only part is that I am not getting the function callback of submitted form since there is no path where the form gets submitted to. here is the jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/ankur20us/jdgadt85/1/

Comment: Jai- $('#info_employee')[0].submit() also doesnt work. Haseena- there is no console error whatsoever

Comment: @Krunal for simplicity i just wrote the php variable there, those variable contain <option> for the <select> tag

Comment: @AnkurVerma i tried your code and move the 'alert(hello)' inside 'submit(function)', then the 'alert' doesnt appear, meaning the 'submit' doesnt work

Comment: Have you tried the link I have given you

Comment: Here is the link with your functions and I am getting the stuff, https://jsfiddle.net/ankur20us/jdgadt85/3/

Comment: Can you tell me how can you tell that you are getting the stuff? and yes i have tried both your links

Comment: See the console you will get the printing